# Where do I get the latest 737NG FCOM?

Tags: boeing-737, boeing

So, I went online to search for the 737 FCOM, but I can only get the FCOM from 2005. Is there a 2019 version? An updated version?

Comment: Generally, you have to pay Boeing lots of money. Or find a copy somebody uploaded to the internet, who shouldn't have. Or, buy a 737. They come included in the price when you do that (or so I've heard). Bottom line, though, it's not intended to be a public document... as the one you have probably say on the cover or on the first few pages.

Comment: @RalphJ then how do people on aviation stack exchange quote FCOM? Do they use the outdated one?

Comment: They probably were issued one by their employer -- who presumably purchased some number of Boeing jets.  Or they used an old one like you found on the internet.

Comment: @RalphJ right thanks

Comment: Just to add to the discussion, an FCOM will typically be specific to an airline. Each aircraft tends to be unique with minor variants, hence each FCOM is typically unique. However, for the sake of ease of reference, the airline with multiple orders of the same variant may have one FCOM, listing differences between individual aircraft registrations with tabulation numbers. Furthermore, an airline can work with Boeing to incorporate its own SOPs along with the AFM standard procedures to an FCOM (Volume 1).